# how to book Emirates ticket without surname in Travelport GDS

Tags: air-travel, tickets, emirates, gds

I want to create PNR in Travelport GDS on Emirates Airlines.
Name of the Traveller is "Gaurav Kumar" but this whole name is written under Given Name and Surname/Family Name is Empty.

How to proceed with that?

Comment: Is the given name and surname presented together in the "given name" field in the traveler's passport, or in the traveler's GDS or Emirates account?

Comment: Yes it is presented together in the traveller's passport in "Given Name" field. and surname/family name is empty

Comment: As a frame challenge: with a passport showing the traveler's name differently from how the passport holder presents the name, this traveler may have challenges from airlines and immigration personnel every time travel is undertaken. If at all possible, the traveler should obtain a new passport showing the name as used by the traveler.

Comment: Now: you're trying to create a PNR using what entity's functionality? Emirates? Travelport? How is this being done, at what URL?

Answer (score 4):

There are some common things that can be used in lieu of a name, but it depends on the carrier.

It's not uncommon to use something like NLN (No last name) or ULN (Unknown last name). Some carriers prefer that you put the same name twice, or incorrectly split the name. I'd reach out to them and see which is preferred on their ticket stock.